# Shooting bullets from SKSpriteNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I try to build 2D - top down game, and I have player (SKSpriteNode) he can move and rotate, and I want to shoot two bullets from him.
I use this code to shoot:

```
func setBullet(player: Player, bullet: Int)
{
    let weaponPosition = scene!.convertPoint(player.weapon.position, fromNode: player)
    var xPos, yPos: CGFloat!

    let sinus = sin(player.zRotation)
    let cosinus = cos(player.zRotation)

    if bullet == 1
    {
        xPos = converted.x - sinus * player.size.height / 2
        yPos = converted.y + cosinus * player.size.height / 2
    }
    else if bullet == 2
    {
        xPos = weaponPosition.x - sinus * player.size.height / 2
        yPos = weaponPosition.y + cosinus * player.size.height / 2
    }

    position = CGPoint(x: xPos, y: yPos)
    physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -sinus * normalSpeed, dy: cosinus * normalSpeed))
}
```

But, i do not know how to correctly set the position...
I try to make something like this[image: this]
(Green dots - this is a bullets).   Can anyone help me please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shooting multiple bullets in the same direction is fairly straightforward. The key is to determine the bullets' initial positions and direction vectors when the character is rotated.

You can calculate a bullet's initial position within the scene by

```
let point = node.convertPoint(weapon.position, toNode: self)
```

where `node` is the character, `weapon.position` is non-rotated position of a gun, and `self` is the scene.

Typically, a bullet moves to the right, `CGVector(dx:1, dy:0)`, or up, `CGVector (dx:0, dy:1)`, when the character is not rotated. You can calculate the direction of the impulse to apply to the bullet's physics body by rotating the vector by the character's `zRotation` with

```
func rotate(vector:CGVector, angle:CGFloat) -> CGVector {
    let rotatedX = vector.dx * cos(angle) - vector.dy * sin(angle)
    let rotatedY = vector.dx * sin(angle) + vector.dy * cos(angle)
    return CGVector(dx: rotatedX, dy: rotatedY)
}
```

Here's an example of how to shoot two bullets from a rotated character:

```
struct Weapon {
    var position:CGPoint
}

class GameScene: SKScene {
    let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")
    let dualGuns = [Weapon(position: CGPoint(x: -15, y: 15)), Weapon(position: CGPoint(x: 15, y: 15))]
    let singleGun = [Weapon(position: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 15))]
    let numGuns = 1
    // If your character faces up where zRotation == 0, offset by pi
    let rotationOffset = CGFloat(M_PI_2)
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        scaleMode = .ResizeFill
        sprite.position = view.center
        sprite.size = CGSizeMake(25, 25)
        self.addChild(sprite)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if let _ = touches.first {
            let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI_4/2), duration:1)
            sprite.runAction(action) {
                [weak self] in
                if let scene = self {
                    switch (scene.numGuns) {
                    case 1:
                        for weapon in scene.singleGun {
                            scene.shoot(weapon: weapon, from: scene.sprite)
                        }
                    case 2:
                        for weapon in scene.dualGuns {
                            scene.shoot(weapon: weapon, from: scene.sprite)
                        }
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func shoot(weapon weapon:Weapon, from node:SKNode) {
        // Convert the position from the character's coordinate system to scene coodinates
        let converted = node.convertPoint(weapon.position, toNode: self)

        // Determine the direction of the bullet based on the character's rotation
        let vector = rotate(CGVector(dx: 0.25, dy: 0), angle:node.zRotation+rotationOffset)

        // Create a bullet with a physics body
        let bullet = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.blueColor(), size: CGSizeMake(4,4))
        bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 2)
        bullet.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        bullet.position = CGPointMake(converted.x, converted.y)
        addChild(bullet)
        bullet.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(vector)
    }

    // Rotates a point (or vector) about the z-axis
    func rotate(vector:CGVector, angle:CGFloat) -> CGVector {
        let rotatedX = vector.dx * cos(angle) - vector.dy * sin(angle)
        let rotatedY = vector.dx * sin(angle) + vector.dy * cos(angle)
        return CGVector(dx: rotatedX, dy: rotatedY)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but can you write code just for correct position, not for vector?

Comment: I will be check it now :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your player is a circle maked with `SKShapeNode` or `SKSpriteNode`.

Both of them have the frame property:

```
let f = player.frame
```

So, the first bullet can be in this position:

```
let firstBullet.position = CGPointMake(player.position.x-(f.width/2),player.position.y)
let secondBullet.position = CGPointMake(player.position.x+(f.width/2),player.position.y)
```

To know it during rotation do:

```
let firstBulletXPos = firstBullet.position.x - sinus * bullet.size.height / 2
let firstBulletYPos = firstBullet.position.y + cosinus * bullet.size.height / 2

let secondBulletXPos = secondBullet.position.x - sinus * bullet.size.height / 2
let secondBulletYPos = secondBullet.position.y + cosinus * bullet.size.height / 2
```

Comment: Thank you, but my player can rotate and positions of bullets is not correct!

Comment: Can your describe what happened?